# Discord.js channels.create is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been making a bot that creates a support channel when a member reacts to a message. It sends an embed waiting for reactions just fine but when I react to the message, which should create a new channel for me, it throws an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: guild.channels.create is not a constructor`. It doesn't tell from which line it's throwing that.

This is the block of code where the error is being thrown:

```
} else if(reaction.message.channel.id == supportChannelID){
        console.log('support');
        if(reaction.emoji.name== ''){
            let guild = reaction.message.guild;
            let supportChannel = new guild.channels.create(`Podpora - ${user.username}`)
                type: text,
                supportChannel.overwritePermissions([
                {
                    id: memberRole,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: user.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    allow: ['READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
                    allow: ['ATTACH_FILES'],
                },
                ])
            console.log('created channel');
            let supportChannelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(1752220)
                .setAuthor("Azuremic", "https://i.imgur.com/m4hkkIj.png")
                .addFields(
                    {name: `Podpora ${user.username}`, value: 'Počkej na někoho z Admin Teamu prosím'}
                )
                .setFooter("Reaguj pomocí ⛔ ke smazání channelu")
                client.channels.cache.get(supportChannel).send(supportChannelEmbed).then(supportChannelEmbed.react('⛔'));
                console.log('sent support embed');
            client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) =>{
                if(user.bot) return;
                if(reaction.message.channel.id == supportChannel.id){
                    if(reaction === '⛔'){
                        supportChannel.delete();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error mentions `guild.channels.create` is not a constructor, so you should not use the `new` keyword.

Also, there are more errors, to fix them see the snippet below:

```js
let supportChannel = await guild.channels.create(`Podpora - ${user.username}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: memberRole,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
      id: user.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
      allow: ['READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'],
      allow: ['ATTACH_FILES'],
    },
  ],
});
```

And you should NOT use `client.on('messageReactionAdd')` inside your command handler

Comment: I pasted in the exact code that you sent, but it crashes with an uncaught error on line 61 ```let supportChannel = await guild.channels.create(`Podpora - ${user.username}`, {``` saying "No debugger available, can not send 'variables'"

Comment: I'm not sure what that error means, but seems to be related to VSCode. Are you in an async function?

Comment: ok I fixed that, it was because I forgot to make that function asynchronous. It created the channel succesfully, but now it throws error when sending a message there saying `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` on the line `client.channels.cache.get(supportChannel).send(supportChannelEmbed).then(supportChannelEmbed.react('⛔'));` I thought that I defined the variable when I made the channel?

Comment: Pass the id of the channel instead: `client.channels.cache.get(supportChannel.id)`